# Trigger atualiza apenas para 1 registro

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, trigger

Considerando a seguinte `trigger`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_vendas_d
ON vendas
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @valor DECIMAL(10,2),
          @data  DATETIME;

  SELECT @data = d.data,
         @valor = d.valor
    FROM deleted d

  UPDATE c
     SET saldo_final = saldo_final - @valor
    FROM caixa c
   WHERE c.data = @data
END
GO
```

Caso mais de um registro seja apagado, apenas o último valor é atualizado. Considerando isso, tenho duas perguntas:

1) Por que isso acontece?

2) Como corrigir o problema da maneira eficiente?

Comment: http://www.devmedia.com.br/cursores-no-sqlserver/5590 , você vai precisar de um Cursor

Comment: @Motta exatamente. Tem essa forma e uma sem cursor também. Você pode adicionar a resposta?

Comment: @Sorack: quando a linha de uma venda é apagada, o saldo de caixa não deveria ser atualizado também para as demais datas posteriores?  Isto é, o saldo de caixa de um dia é utilizado como saldo inicial no dia seguinte OU o saldo é controlado individualmente para cada dia?

Comment: @JoséDiz sim... Esse problema não é real, é só um exemplo que eu coloquei pra facilitar o entendimento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso ocorre, pois quando você faz um delete em múltiplas linhas num mesmo statement, ele ativa a trigger somente uma vez e na sua tabela temporária `deleted`, vai ter a lista de todos os deletados.

Existem varias soluções para o seu problema, você poderia fazer um cursos por exemplo e rodar o seu update varias vezes, não recomento muito fazer isso por questões de performance, outra seria adaptar seu update para prever uma lista e não um valor único que está vindo da variável igual você está fazendo.

Sua trigger ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_vendas_d
ON vendas
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN


  UPDATE c
     SET saldo_final = saldo_final - (SELECT SUM(d.valor) FROM deleted d WHERE d.data = c.caixa)
    FROM caixa c
   WHERE c.data  in (SELECT d.data FROM deleted d)
END
GO
```

Comment: Me parece que se esqueceu de retirar o SELECT do código original do procedimento trigger. Inclusive provavelmente ocorre erro na execução, pela não declaração das variáveis @ data e @ valor.

Comment: Muito obrigado, tinha esquecido mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Há algumas semanas estou escrevendo artigos sobre as armadilhas na programação de procedimentos *trigger* em SQL Server. A questão do procedimento *trigger* tratar somente uma linha é um dos casos mais comuns. É necessário ficar atento que um procedimento *trigger* pode ser acionado para tratar nenhuma, uma ou várias linhas.

Eis uma solução simples:

```
-- código #1
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_vendas_d
   ON vendas
   after DELETE as
BEGIN

-- encerra o processamento se não há linha para tratar
IF not exists (SELECT * from DELETED) return;

-- atualiza saldo de caixa
UPDATE C
  set saldo_final = C.saldo_final - D.valor
  from caixa as C
       inner join DELETED as D on D.data = C.data;

END;
GO
```